# Editing the same message every few minutes

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to code a discord bot that edits the same message that it just sent every few minutes, I have some code already written but it only edits it once. I'm new to this style of thing, any idea what could be wrong or what I need to do?

This is supposed to edit with my FiveM Server but I want to get the editing part done first

I've tried using `setTimeout()` in my message but it only edits the message once.

```
const config = require("./config.js");
const request = require('request');

const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

var ip = "Private"
var port = "30120"
var timeoutvar = "60000"

const players = request(`http://${ip}:${port}/players.json`, function (players, error, response, body) {
  console.log('body:', body);
});

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

// Set the bot's presence (activity and status)
client.on("ready", () => {
  client.user.setPresence({
      game: { 
          name: 'MODPS',
          type: 'WATCHING'
      },
      status: 'dnd'
  })
})

client.on('message', msg => {
  client.channels.get("channelid").send(`${players}`)
  .then((msg) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      msg.edit(`${players}`)
    }, 2000)}
  )}
)

client.login(token);
```

Expected result: the message to be edited at least every minute or so.

Actual result: only edits the same message once.

Comment: Try to use `setInterval()` method.

Comment: how would i like set it so it doesn't reply the same message and edit it again?

Answer (score 1):

60,000 milliseconds = 60 seconds. `setInterval` executes the given function each `x` milliseconds:

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  client.channels.get("channelid").send(`${players}`)
  .then((msg) => {
    setInterval(function() {
    msg.edit(`${players}`)
  }, 60000)}
  )}
)
```

Comment: it works :) only when i send a message so i edited it instead of message i put ready

Comment: @Rhys19: When do you need it to be edited? It works when a message is send because the code is registered under `client.on('message'...` event.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) method.

> The `setInterval()` method repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call.

```
client.on('message', msg => {
    client.channels.get("channelid").send(`${players}`)
    .then((msg) => {
        setInterval(function() {
            msg.edit(`${players}`)
        }, 1000)} /* 1000 ms = 1 second */
    )}
)
```

Here is the basic example of `setInterval()` method:

```js
setInterval(function(){
  console.log('Hello World');
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked:

```
client.on('ready', msg => {
  client.channels.get("555945877483814915").send(`${players}`)
  .then((msg) => {
    setInterval(function() {
    msg.edit(`${players}`)
  }, 60000)}
  )}
)
```

Comment: this is showing the message was edited but it won't show the new data i am trying to use a request.get to update a players list from my FiveM server any clue why it's not updating the player's ping? even if i do message.createdAt it doesn't work. code: https://pastebin.com/6avxSMhr